# not able to hit spring controller

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I have simple form action with spring below . Not able to hit the controller on click of submit . Whats wrong . I am using spring 4.3.17

index.jsp

```
<form action="/springold/ecSearch" method="get">
 First name: <input type="text" name="fname"><br>
 Last name: <input type="text" name="lname"><br>
 <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 </form>
```

web.xml

```
servlet>
    <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
   </servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/springold/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml :

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com"/>
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Controller class :

```
package com;
 import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
 import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
public class ECActivityController {


@RequestMapping(value="/ecSearch", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public   void proccess(){
    System.out.println("done");

}
```

}

Comment: try to use `@RestController` instead of `@Controller`

Comment: not working with @RestController as well . I have set the context root as springtest
Please help

Comment: Try changing `<url-pattern>/springold/*</url-pattern>` to `<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>` and see if you can GET `/springold/ecSearch`. You shouldn't repeat your context path in the `<url-pattern>` value.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that url in form is correct and `/springold` is a root of context path.
But I see here other issue, the form is passes two params: `lname` and `lname`.
So your method of controller have to seems like that:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ecSearch", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void proccess(@RequestParam("fname") String fname, @RequestParam("lname") String lname) {
    System.out.println("done");
}
```